# Query a sequence of data from ORACLE DB and Save the values in an PHP array

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I need to run a query and save the values in a PHP array. So that in the later time, I could pass the array into json and even run `sizeof()` for data manipulation. so far my query is this,

```
   WITH DATA
     AS (SELECT TO_DATE ('2012-01-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date1,
                TO_DATE ('2012-02-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date2
           FROM DUAL)
 SELECT TO_CHAR (date1 + LEVEL - 1) datename,
        TO_CHAR (date1 + LEVEL - 1, 'fmMonth') month_name,
        TO_CHAR (date1 + LEVEL - 1, 'IW') the_week,
        TO_CHAR (date1 + LEVEL - 1, 'D') the_day,
        TO_CHAR (date1 + LEVEL - 1, 'DAY') the_day_name
   FROM data
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= date2 - date1 + 1
```

and the php is,

```
$days = array();
            while ($row = oci_fetch_array($dateHeaderParse)){ 
                $days = $row['THE_DAY'];
            }
            ?>
```

and when i execute withthis,

```
    print_r($days);
```

its only returning two, which supposed to be more than two. The query is perfectly working.

Please help me

Comment: You're using `$days = $row['THE_DAY'];` - shouldn't it be `array_push($days, $row['THE_DAY']);`?

Comment: thank you, can you post the answer again so i can make it an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you loop through the results from `oci_fetch_array`, you're setting `$days` to the current result, and discarding the previous value. You should actually be appending the results into `$days` like this:

```
$days = array();
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($dateHeaderParse)){ 
    array_push($days, $row['THE_DAY']);
}
```

I'm not a PHP developer, so this may not work, but you may be able to do this using `oci_fetch_all` and `array_map`, like this:

```
$days = array_map(function($row) {return $row['THE_DAY'];},
    oci_fetch_all($dateHeaderParse));
```